# How to add menu link when activate the wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, menu, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress plugin. I have some links for showing product Brands name and Product categories listing, in the url: http://testsite.com/product-categories and http://testsite.com/brands like that. So I want this link will be auto generated when plugin is activated and place in the default menu in Wordpress. How can I do that. I tried this code but its not working.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'myplugin_activate' ) );

public function myplugin_activate() {
    $product_categories = array(
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_name'      => 'product-categories',
                'post_title'     => 'Product Categories',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'post_type'      => 'nav_menu_item',
            );

    $brands = array(
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_name'      => 'brands',
                'post_title'     => 'Brands',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'post_type'      => 'nav_menu_item',
            );

    wp_insert_post( $product_categories );
    wp_insert_post( $brands );
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that? One thing I can not do that as page post type.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `wp_insert_post` and `nav_menu_item`, I found [*Programmatically add a Navigation menu and menu items*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/44736/12615) where `wp_create_nav_menu` is suggested.

Should be a matter of using the functions [`wp_get_nav_menu_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_object), [`wp_create_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nav_menu), [`wp_update_nav_menu_item`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_update_nav_menu_item/) and [`get_nav_menu_locations`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_nav_menu_locations/).